# Fix for JQUERY UI resize right aligned element

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I am using jQueryUI resize option in an angular project. I applied the `resize` for `img-preview-data` and the handles as `sw, se`. Now resize from `se` is working perfectly and it does not go out of the boundary.

However when I try to resize from `sw`, and stop at a particular location, then I could only resize it smaller and could not resize it bigger.

Please help in finding a solution for this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img-preview-data").resizable({
    autoHide: false,
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: "se, sw",
    containment: "parent"
  });
});
```

```css
<div id="img-main-container" class="ng-scope" style="height: 78px; width: 720px;border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div id="img-container" style="position:absolute; display:block; height: 76px; width: 718px;">
    <div id="img-preview-data" class="alignRight" style="width: 85px; height: 76px; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="someURL" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </div>
    <canvas id="resize-canvas" width="83" height="76"></canvas>
  </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="img-main-container" class="ng-scope" style="height: 78px; width: 720px;border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div id="img-container" style="position:absolute; display:block; height: 76px; width: 718px;">
    <div id="img-preview-data" class="alignRight" style="width: 85px; height: 76px; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="someURL" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </div>
    <canvas id="resize-canvas" width="83" height="76"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working link to your fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle link was broken, presumably in your attempt to get around the restrictions on fiddle links with no code in the question. I edited the question to include your code - as you will need to do for all future questions.

Comment: Here is my working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mohankumarpr/k6s4stou/1/